# Limit of the periodic sequence's arithmetic mean

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

The problem was originally proposed on the national stage of russian national students math olympiad, Sep 2018.

Let sequence $x_{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$, with positive elements - periodic: there exists such $p \in \mathbb{N}$, that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $x_{n} = x_{n+p}$. Proof, that sequence of the arithmetic mean $\bar{x}_{n} = { {x_{1} + x_{2} + \dots + x_{n}} \over {n} }, n \in \mathbb{N}$ has a limit; find this limit.

As a participant, I didn't solve it then. My thoughts was:

Let $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\bar{x}_{n} = l$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\bar{x}_{n+p} = l$. Let $t_{n} = \bar{x}_{n + p} - \bar{x}_{n}$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}t_{n} = 0$. For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N_{\epsilon}$ such that $n \ge N_{\epsilon}$ implies $\left | t_{n} \right | \le \epsilon$. We have:

$\left | t_{n} \right | = \left | { {x_{1 + p} + x_{2 + p} + \dots + x_{n+  p}} \over {n+p} } - { {x_{1} + x_{2} + \dots + x_{n}} \over {n} } \right | = \left | {{p} \over {(n + p)}} \cdot { {x_{1} + x_{2} + \dots + x_{n}} \over {n} }  \right |$.

$ \left | t_{n} \right | \le \left | {{p} \over {(n + p)} }l  \right |$. Letting $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have $\left | t_{n} \right | \le \epsilon $.
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitary we get: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left | t_{n} \right | = 0$. Thus, a limit of sequence $\bar{x}_{n}$ exists.

However, I have no idea how to find this limit. Moreover, I'm not really sure that my proof of the limit existence is correct.

Comment: You cannot assume the limit is $l$ before showing the limit even exists. I assume there as a type; actually it seems that $t_n = \bar x_{n+p} - \bar x$. But anyway $\lim_{n \to \infty} |t_n| = 0$ is not sufficient to show that the limit actually exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have an explicit formula for $\bar{x}_n$ using the fact that the sequence is periodic
$$
\bar{x}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i = \frac{1}{n}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor\sum_{i=1}^px_i + \sum_{j=1}^{n\,\mathrm{mod}\,p}x_i\right) = \frac{\lfloor n/p\rfloor}{n/p}\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{x_i}{p} + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n\, \mathrm{mod}\, p}x_i
$$

From this, it shouldn't be too hard to show
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \bar{x}_n = \frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=1}^px_i,
$$
the arithmetic mean of the elements of the sequence over one period.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reference for an article or a book where this formula appears? I've never seen it.

Comment: @Sftnrg I just split the sum apart into periods. There are $\lfloor n/p\rfloor$ periods less than $n$, and they all have the same $p$ entries in them. The last sum is just the remaining terms not part of a full period.